# Creating an array of times in 24/12 hour format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I just added moment.js to my project and want to create a couple of select boxes with the time of day on every hour and half hour. It would look something like this:

```
['12:00', '12:30', '1:00', '1:30', '2:00', '2:30'...'5:00', '5:30'];
```

I was wondering if there was a way moment.js was capable of generating an array in the same manner it can generate the days of the week:

```
moment.weekdays();
```

Essentially I want to populate my select input with these hourly options as labels and the values in 24 hour format. What would be my best bet here? Would I convert the 12 hour time within my loop or is there an even better option where moment can create an object with both values? Either way, I'm all ears.

Comment: generally: **do not use selects for date inputs!**
But have you tried just something like ``Array(24).fill(null).map((_,i) => i).map(h => [`${h}:00`, `${h}:30`]).flat()``?

Comment: I think this is cool but I think moment would still have to come into play to convert back to 24 hour time.

Comment: why? this is 24 hours. And for 12h just use modulo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#from` to create array of times

```js
const hours = Array.from({
  length: 48
}, (_, hour) => moment({
    hour: Math.floor(hour / 2),
    minutes: (hour % 2 === 0 ? 0 : 30)
  }).format('HH:mm')
);
console.log(hours);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution more human readable with moment.

```
const startOfDay = moment().startOf('day');
const hours = Array(48).fill(null).map((_, i) => startOfDay.add(i ? 30 : 0, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can always do something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script >
  const generateHour = () => {
    const arrHours = []
    for (let h = 0; h < 48; h++) {
      arrHours.push(moment({
        hour: Math.floor(h / 2),
        minute: h % 2 === 0 ? 0 : 30
      }).format('HH:mm'))
    }
    console.log(arrHours)
 }
generateHour()
</script>
```